# How to check who created database in impala

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala

I have one Hadoop cluster (Cloudera distribution) given access to multiple user. Now from different users we are creating databases. How do i verify which user is creating which database.? Can anyone suggest me.?

Comment: If Sentry is enabled, then everything will be owned by `hive`... Otherwise you can try the Metastore Java API (the long, complex and tricky way) or run a SQL query on the Metastore DB, if you have the admin user/pwd (the fast and dirty way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below query:

```
Describe formatted databaseName.tableName;
```

Will show the owner and other details like **table type,size etc.**

Comment: What if database is not having any tables.?